# Merge getSymbols data by ticker and date

Tags: r, xts, quantmod, quandl

I'm currently learning R and I'm just trying to pull in some price data using getSymbols in the quantmod package.

I have a dataframe that has tickers and dates of annual results releases for a sector on the Australian Stock Exchange. What I'd like to do is merge in an adjusted price for the day of the release as well as the price 5 days before and 5 days after.

```
Ticker  Ann_Rep_Date  Ad.Price  +5d.Ad.Price  -5d.Ad.Price
AGI.AX  14/10/16
ALL.AX  22/12/16
CWN.AX  19/09/16
TAH.AX  4/08/16
TAH.AX  4/08/17
TTS.AX  17/08/17
```

Note that there can be multiple prices required for a single ticker as there are multiple annual results releases.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do this using tqget from tidyquant. It can store all my prices in one big happy data frame which makes it easy to merge with the above.

```
library(tidyquant)

prices <- c('TBH.AX','CWN.AX','SGR.AX','AQS.AX','ALL.AX',
        'TAH.AX','JIN.AX','TTS.AX','AGI.AX') %>%
         tq_get(get = 'stock.prices')

Ann_Reps <- merge(prices, Ann_Reps, by.x=c('symbol','date'), 
by.y=c('ticker','Ann_Rep_Date'))
```